# How can read number and put the number in array of object

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have file.txt like

> 7 10 5
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV221 Jeddah NewYork 30 7000
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV223 Jeddah London 30 4000
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV225 Jeddah Paris 30 3500
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV227 Jeddah Cairo 30 2000
>   ADD_PASS Mohammed Ali 33 M 0555788778
>   ADD_PASS Sara Maghrabi 30 F 0555111111
>   ADD_PASS Hani Ali 20 M 0555223344
>   ADD_PASS Mohammed Hafeth 33 M 0555889876
>   ADD_PASS Ahmad Sami 44 M 0555768768
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV332 Jeddah Riyadh 20 500
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV334 Jeddah Dammam 20 600
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV367 Jeddah Dubai 25 2000
>   ADD_PASS Salwa Ali 33 F 0555765672
>   ADD_PASS Faisal Amri 20 M 0555111111
>   ADD_PASS Mona Saleem 33 F 0555222112
>   ADD_PASS Ali Ali 33 M 0555743344
>   ADD_PASS Marwa Ahmad 33 F 0555545855

I want read number 7 and put the number in array of object

My code

```
File fin = new File("input.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (fin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (fis));
System.out.println(br.readLine());
String []t=br.readLine().split( "1");
for (int i=0;i<t.length;i++){
    System.out.println(t[i]);
```

Is not correct because the output is

> ADD_FLIGHT SV221

Put I want read number 7 and put the number in array of object

Help please:(

Comment: what is your expected output. I'm a bit confused

Comment: To clarify, you just want to find the number 7 and put it into the array???

Comment: i want take number 7 and put the number like this >> flight []a =new [7]:

Answer (score 1):

I think that you waste your first line printing it

```
//It reads and prints "7 10 5" 
System.out.println(br.readLine());
//Reads "ADD_FLIGHT SV221 Jeddah NewYork 30 7000" and splits it at "1" 
String []t=br.readLine().split( "1"); 
//t contains "ADD_FLIGHT SV22" and " Jeddah NewYork 30 7000"
for (int i=0;i<1;i++){
    //Prints "ADD_FLIGHT SV22"
    System.out.println(t[i]); 
}
```

You should:

```
File fin = new File("input.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (fin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (fis));
//Reads first line and split it at every "space"
String []t=br.readLine().split(" "); 
//t contains "7" "10" "5"
System.out.println(t[0]);
//t[0] contains 7, and you can put this value into your array
```

Comment: The output not 7 ))) ADD_FLIGHT  >>the output of your code

Comment: I've edited, do you do something before reading the first line? Like in my code?

Comment: The output of your edited error :( ... Do you  have another solution

Comment: There is no need for using a FileInputStream, and the InputStreamReader since we are already using a text file. It should go from `File fin = new File("input.txt");` to `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fin))`